# Checking if UITextView has url (boolean value) or extract Url

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, nsurl, nsdatadetector

I am aware I can do `textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;` to auto detect links.

Now this seems straightforward but I can't find a way to check if the `UITextView`'s dataDetector actually found a match.

I'm looking for something like `BOOL hasLink = textView.hasLink;` or `BOOL hasLink = textView.text.hasLink;` or maybe even a way to pull a reference to the `NSDataDetector`(I could probably use `NSDataDetector` methods to check but I'd have to confirm, just throwing out ideas)

Is there no built in way to check this or do I have to confirm it independently?

## Edit:

So I just used my own `NSDataDetector` to do this, (code below) but the question remains as to whether there really is no way of extracting a detected data type or confirming the existence of a detected data type in a `UITextView`?

This is what I used to check myself:

```
-(BOOL) doesTextHaveLink:(NSString *)text {
    NSDataDetector *linkDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
    NSArray *matches = [linkDetector matchesInString:text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])];
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
        if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: you whant to check textView contane url or not ?

Answer (score 0):

plz use this code this return yes if textview has url

```
-(BOOL)checkUrl:(NSString *)strText{
    NSString *urlRegEx =
    @"(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";
    NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx]; 
    return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:strText];
}
```

Comment: I think the solution I posted under the Edit header is probably a safer alternative to this